# Is this correlated equilibrium welfare-maximizing?

Tags: game-theory

My question is about an unsourced sentence in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_equilibrium

(emphasis mine)

> [image]
> The following correlated equilibrium has an even higher payoff to both players: Recommend (C, C) with probability 1/2, and (D, C) and (C, D) with probability 1/4 each. Then when a player is recommended to play C, she knows that the other player will play D with (conditional) probability 1/3 and C with probability 2/3, and gets expected payoff 14/3, which is equal to (not less than) the expected payoff when she plays D. **In this correlated equilibrium, both players get 5.25 in expectation. It can be shown that this is the correlated equilibrium with maximal sum of expected payoffs to the two players.**

Why does this correlated equilibrium have the maximal sum of expected payoffs? Why is it not the correlated equilibrium with (D,C) probability 1/2 and (C,D) probability 1/2. Isn't that a correlated equilibrium (neither player will deviate if they know their opponent's action)? And isn't the sum of payoffs = 9 for that?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I am daft. In the 1/2, 1/4, 1/4 CE, **each** player gets an EV of 5.25. With the 0, 1/2, 1/2 CE, each player gets an EV of 4.5.